# How to forward messages to Sentry with a clean scope (no runtime information)

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, sentry

I'm forwarding alert messages from a AWS Lambda function to Sentry using the sentry_sdk in Python.
The problem is that even if I use `scope.clear()` before `capture_message()` the events I receive in sentry are enriched with information about the runtime environment where the message is captured in (the AWS lambda python environment) - which in this scenario is completly unrelated to the actual alert I'm forwarding.

My Code:

```
sentry_sdk.init(dsn, environment="name-of-stage")
with sentry_sdk.push_scope() as scope:
  # Unfortunately this does not get rid of lambda specific context information.  
  scope.clear()  
  # here I set relevant information which works just fine.
  scope.set_tag("priority", "high") 
  result = sentry_sdk.capture_message("mymessage")
```

The behaviour does not change if I pass `scope` as an argument to `capture_message()`.

The tag I set manually is beeing transmitted just fine. But I also receive information about the Python runtime - therefore `scope.clear()` either does not behave like I expect it to OR `capture_message` gathers additional information itself.

Can someone explain how to only capture the information I'm actively assigning to the scope with set_tag and similar functions and surpress everything else?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I didn't find an explaination for the behaviour I was able to solve my problem (Even though it' a little bit hacky).

The solution was to use the sentry `before_send` hook in the init step like so:

```
sentry_sdk.init(dsn, environment="test", before_send=cleanup_event)
with sentry_sdk.push_scope() as scope:
  sentry_sdk.capture_message(message, state, scope)
# when using sentry from lambda don't forget to flush otherwise messages can get lost.
sentry_sdk.flush()
```

Then in the cleanup_event function it gets a little bit ugly. I basically iterate over the keys of the event and remove the ones I do not want to show up. Since some Keys hold objects and some (like "tags") are a list  with [key, value] entries this was quite some hassle.

```
KEYS_TO_REMOVE = {
   "platform": [],
   "modules": [],
   "extra": ["sys.argv"],
   "contexts": ["runtime"],
}
TAGS_TO_REMOVE = ["runtime", "runtime.name"]

def cleanup_event(event, hint):
  for (k, v) in KEYS_TO_REMOVE.items():
    with suppress(KeyError):
        if v:
            for i in v:
                del event[k][i]
        else:
            del event[k]
  for t in event["tags"]:
    if t[0] in TAGS_TO_REMOVE:
        event["tags"].remove(t)
  return event
```